# Why .reg file import to registry does not work in Vista 64-bit Operating system?

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, windows-registry

I am trying to add some .reg file info to windows registry using command line utility.

```
regedit /s myregfile.reg
```

I am able to add tree in registry in 32-bit and 64-bit windows XP machine.
But when i do same for windows vista 64-bit machine , it does not add the tree into registry.

Why is does not work in vista 64-bit OS and 
Can anybody suggest me how to do it for vista 64-bit ?

Answer (score 2):

What registry keys do you modify with that file? Could it be that you simply don't have permission to access them? Remember that the user in Vista does not by default has administrative privileges, even if they are an Administrator.

Comment: Even I also though for it but I have admin access still i am not able to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run the command line as administrator (Start -> Run -> Type 'cmd' -> Ctrl Enter

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked for the key under HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node - see http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/internals-and-architecture/what-s-the-wow6432node-under-the-hkey_local_machine-software-registry-subkey-.aspx

Comment: I think this might well be the case. (Was about to write that myself. )